# Error in loading column with CHAR(13) in Devexpress XtraReports

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I generate report from a SQL Server Source (stored procedure) and I have something like

```
SELECT ID, (Name + CHAR(13) + Number) AS Info
FROM Table
```

When I try to generate my report in web I get an error of

> Unable to cast object of type System.String[] to System.IConvertible

I've ran through this issue before and what I did was to set the **Multiline** property of the cell to `true` then everything works fine.  But now it doesn't seem to fix my problem? What else am I missing?

Or is there other way for me to concatenate two columns in a single cell if i'm using a Data Binding in serverside and not from the stored procedure?

Comment: I assume that you move the data into your report via the report constructor.  If you are doing it this way, one of your lines of code in your constructor would be to assign the data to the bindingsource object in the report.  What I do is to modify the data inside the object being assigned to the binding source BEFORE it is applied to the bindsource inside the report constructor.. I you want an example of this, say so and I'll post as the answer.  Another way to concatenate is to use a calculated field within xtrareports.

Comment: may be this is a bug and you can send a sample project or a stacktrace to the support

Comment: @Wizengamot not sure if you're trying to say is before print? but if that's what you meant, it's not applicable for the way the reports are generated here because what's inside our constructor and before print are just filtering parameters for the specific report.

Comment: No... I pass the data into my Devexpress reports via the constructor.  Generally my data exists in a standard POCO object that is designed for that report and has the data I need in the report.  In your case, I am not sure how you are passing the data to the report because if your report is fetching the data directly from the SQL server (or other data source) directly then the solution I have in my head will not help.  Can you shed light on how your data is getting into the report (fetched by the report directly from the server or passed into the report via constructor or property?

Comment: I know your generating the data from a stored proc, but how your physically moving the data from the stored proc to the report is the mechanism I am asking about.  If you edit your question and paste in the code that actually fetches the data and then opens the report, I'll have my clarification and I may be able to provide some assistance.

Comment: @Wizengamot hi wiz.. I'm not sure of how my work fixed itself.. but i just restarted visual studio, and the error just went off. thanks for your time and willingness to help